# Solr Search or Views Exposed Filters

Tags: views, search

I have a food recipes site and it has a search feature on home page.

My Questions are :

Once the user search for some thing, they "continue to narrow down the results" . Is it possible with views exposed filters ? or i should be looking into Solar search for  Faceted navigation and Relevancy tuning .

[image]

**Another Search Interface .**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use proper fields that keep the relevant information (either in nodes or custom entities), it is possible that this can be achieved with Views exposed filters (the slider will require some client-side programming). For more search features, you can also use the Search API without needing to get into the complications of Apache Solr.

Comment: Thanks @Wtower, but the problem is "Faceted navigation" which is shown in the left side bar . and i am thinking to use taxonomy to classify the faceted navigation. VIEWS can help with "faceted navigation"?

Comment: I believe they can. It would be a separate view displaying taxonomy terms in block. Not that I am against Solr too, just saying the possibilities.

Comment: great. I have another thought with Exposed filters. In the second interface above, i will expose the "recipe-title" field. but if the user enters "chili", "asian" or name of the ingredient then nothing will show up ..

Comment: I understand. For details about the Search API you can take a look at (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102983/default-search-not-working-for-taxonomy-terms/102984#102984) and the links in it.